# Binding interface issue: Argument 1 passed to __construct() must implement interface

Tags: laravel

I have an issue when I try to bind `StripePaymentGateway` to `PaymentGatewayInteface`

```php
namespace App\Billing;

interface PaymentGatewayInteface
{
    public function charge($amount, $token);
}
```

```php
namespace App\Billing;

use Stripe\Charge;

class StripePaymentGateway
{
    private $apiKey;

    public function __construct($apiKey)
    {
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
    }

    public function charge($amount, $token)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

My AppServiceProvider:

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Billing\StripePaymentGateway;
use App\Billing\PaymentGatewayInteface;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(StripePaymentGateway::class, function () {
            return new StripePaymentGateway(config('services.stripe.secret'));
        });

        $this->app->bind(PaymentGatewayInteface::class, StripePaymentGateway::class);
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Billing\PaymentGatewayInteface;

class ConcertsOrdersController extends Controller
{
    private $paymentGateway;

    public function __construct(PaymentGatewayInteface $paymentGateway)
    {
        $this->paymentGateway = $paymentGateway;
    }
}
```

This error is showing:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ConcertsOrdersController::__construct() must implement interface App\Billing\PaymentGatewayInteface, instance of App\Billing\StripePaymentGateway given
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is saying that it is expecting a class that implements `PaymentGatewayInteface`.
To do this you need to explicitly say that a class is implementing an interface like you would when `extending` a class:

```
class StripePaymentGateway implements PaymentGatewayInteface
```